# Python pip installed but virtualenv not installing

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

When I type `pip` it gives me following error

```
C:\Users\DJ PC>pip<br>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py",<br>
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py",<br>
    exec code in run_globals<br>
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe<br>
  File "C:\Python27\pip.py", line 1<br>
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)<br>
  File "C:\Python27\pip.py", line 1<br>
    cert.write(pkgutil.get_data("pi<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py"<br>
    loader = get_loader(package)<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py"<br>
    return find_loader(fullname)<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py"<br>
    for importer in iter_importers(<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py"<br>
    __import__(pkg)<br>
ImportError: No module named _vendo<br>
```

I wanted to install `virtualenv` on my pc using pip.

Answer (score 0):

Running pip alone doesn't make sense 
You should run: `pip install virtualenv`